# How to convert tar file to tar.gz using Python only?

Tags: python-3.x, tar, gzip, tarfile

I looking for how converting tar file to tar.gz using only Python code?
I have been tried many issues but nothing work
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tarfile.html
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/gzip.html

I obtain different error:

with gzip.open, he create a "gz" file with "tar" in it

```
import gzip

tarfile = "/home/user/file.tar"
with open(tarfile, 'rb') as f_in:
    with gzip.open(tarfile+'.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
        f_out.writelines(f_in)
```

with copy.deepcopy + gzip compress, I have 'TextIOWrapper' or 'BufferedReader' with deepcopy function

```
import gzip, copy
tarfile = "/home/user/file.tar"

with open(tarfile, 'rb') as f_in:
    data = copy.deepcopy(f_in)
with open(tarfile+'.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
        try:
            gdata = gzip.compress(data)
            f_out.write(gdata)
        except Exception as e:
            print("error: %s" % (e))
```

gzip.compress + write, I have "BufferedReader"

```
import gzip

tarfile = "/home/user/file.tar"
with open(tarfile, 'rb') as f_in:   
    with open(tarfile+'.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
        try:
            data = gzip.compress(f_in)
            f_out.write(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print("error: %s" % (e))
```

So, I need help.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53205586/edit) your question and paste a sample of your code/what you tried?

Comment: done, It's edited

Comment: Your first one works fine. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to simply extract the tar-file to a temporary directory and then recompress it as a `tar.gz`:

```
import tarfile, shutil

TARFILE = "/home/user/file.tar"
TMP_DIR = ".tar_gz_converter_tmp"

with tarfile.open(TARFILE ) as f:
    f.extractall(TMP_DIR)

with tarfile.open(TARFILE + ".gz", "w:gz") as f:
    f.add(TMP_DIR, ".")

shutil.rmtree(TMP_DIR)
```

Note how `tarfile` can compress a file as `tar.gz` if you set the mode to `w:gz`.
It should also be possible to do the conversion in memory, but it's definitely more complicated.